# How to upgrade ubuntu if i get 'Authenticating the upgrade failed'?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, do-release-upgrade

I want to upgrade my ubuntu 14.04 distribution to the 16.04.

I'm working in a domain buy I have sudo permissions, the repositories point to our private repositories

I try to upgrade with the command do-release upgrade and the application and I got this error.

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [198 B]                                           
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1262 kB]                                                   
Fetched 1262 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                  
authenticate 'xenial.tar.gz' against 'xenial.tar.gz.gpg' 
gpg exited 1
Debug information: 


gpg: Signature made dc 26 oct 2016 16:32:27 CEST using DSA key ID 437D05B5
gpg: /tmp/ubuntu-release-upgrader-gzuou970/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: BAD signature from "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>"

Authentication failed    Authenticating the upgrade failed. There may be a problem with the network or with the server.
```

And when I try to upgrade through Software updater I get this error.

[image]

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the latest version of the update-manager-core installed.

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`

Then re-run do-release-upgrade.

If this still fails, the issue is with your private repository, not locally.

You should manually force a refresh of the private repository, because it's possible the xenial.tar.gz file has changed and your repository has a stale version.

Comment: It seems to be a security problem because I'm in a private domain